# Append two tables - Union not working in SQL (Teradata)

Tags: sql, union, teradata

I'm a beginner with SQL. I'm using Teradata. We're trying to pull the data together to compare actuals versus forecast.

Here is my code:

```
select 
'Actuals' as fc_version,
A.tra_fiscal_year as fiscal_year,
A.tra_fiscal_week as fiscal_week,
A.tra_allocation_category_code as category,
A.tra_grand_pricing_sales_channel as grandparent_channel,
D.fc_prod_id,
coalesce(
case
when A.tra_ticket_product_code like 'A%' then 'Total'
else null
end,

case
when A.tra_grand_pricing_sales_channel = 'INMKT' Then 'In Market'
else 'All Other'
end )
as fc_sales_channel,

sum(A.tra_ticket_quantity) as units_sold,

from ((pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_detail A
left outer join
pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_prod_code_to_fc_id B
on (A.tra_ticket_product_code = B.product_code))
left outer join
pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_ticket_code_to_fc_id C
on (A.tra_ticket_code = C.ticket_code)
left outer join
pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_fc_prod_info D
on (coalesce(B.fc_prod_id, C.fc_prod_id) = D.fc_prod_id))

group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

union

select fc_version, fiscal_year, fiscal_week, category, null as grandparent_channel, fc_prod_id, fc_sales_channel, sum(units_sold) as units_sold
from pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_fc
where fiscal_year = 2017 and fiscal_week = 1
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

If you paste the first part before the union, it has the correct result. Likewise with the second part after the union.

But the entire code together gives the error:
SELECT Failed. [3654] Corresponding select-list expressions are incompatible.

Here is a general idea of the tables I'm using.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have the same number of columns in both parts (top and bottom) as well as the same data type.

As far as I can count there are 9 columns in the top query and 8 in the bottom one.

**UPD**: the fix according to the author is convert null to empty string in the below query.

Comment: Thanks! It was a simple fix of switching a null to a empty quotation.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the same number of columns in the tow select and  (the number seems 8 in both the select )  but
in your union you should not use alias in the second select

```
select 
'Actuals' as fc_version,
A.tra_fiscal_year as fiscal_year,
A.tra_fiscal_week as fiscal_week,
A.tra_allocation_category_code as category,
A.tra_grand_pricing_sales_channel as grandparent_channel,
D.fc_prod_id,
coalesce(
case
when A.tra_ticket_product_code like 'A%' then 'Total'
else null
end,

case
when A.tra_grand_pricing_sales_channel = 'INMKT' Then 'In Market'
else 'All Other'
end )
as fc_sales_channel,

sum(A.tra_ticket_quantity) as units_sold,

from ((pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_detail A
left outer join
pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_prod_code_to_fc_id B
on (A.tra_ticket_product_code = B.product_code))
left outer join
pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_ticket_code_to_fc_id C
on (A.tra_ticket_code = C.ticket_code)
left outer join
pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_fc_prod_info D
on (coalesce(B.fc_prod_id, C.fc_prod_id) = D.fc_prod_id))

group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

union

select 
    fc_version
    , fiscal_year
    , fiscal_week
    , category
    , null 
    , fc_prod_id
    , fc_sales_channel
    , sum(units_sold) 
from pd_plan_forecast_db.adm_rev_fc
where fiscal_year = 2017 and fiscal_week = 1
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Comment: The alias doesn't matter (the result always uses the column name from the 1st Select), it's the datatype which doesn't match. In Teradata a NULL has an INT datatype (don't ask why, it's similar in Oracle)